# Select and upload image admin form magento 2

Tags: image-upload

I have admin form in which I have image upload option.Button "Select" will select a image ,then user click button Upload to upload image.
Finally image name and path will be save when form submit
[image: image field]
It will be great help if someone can help me with this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a new controller.php for inserting data in database.
give url in form action of your controller

```
public function indexAction()    {
         $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template');
        $block->setTemplate('folder/file.phtml');     
        echo $block->toHtml();
        $this->_title($this->__('Customers'))->_title($this->__('Customers Authentication'));
       $this->loadLayout();
     $this->renderLayout();             
    }
```

Comment: **After That** you should create insert Action.php
and pass code here

Comment: Ok . Thanks for your reply. Let me check this code